VBA storing formulas in array
Are you able to store excel formulas in an array? I need to paste the formula into I1, they would be =C4 through =C350 then with each iteration I would have to copy S1 to the cell one over. For example paste =C4 into from an array ideally since so many values into I1 then paste S1 into E1 then got next array value =C5 in I1 then copy S1 to E5 etc.
Sub Macro_data_check()
   Dim Econ() As Variant
   Dim i As Long
   Econ() = Range("C4:C350")

    For i = 1 To 347
     Range(Econ(0)).Select
     Selection.Copy
     Range("I1").Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste
     If Not s1 = 0 Then
     Range("s1").Copy
     Range("E4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
      End If
    
   Next i

This is what I currently have but I need to switch the Econ array to cell values if possible. Then copy it into I1 and copy S1 to E4 or one over from the associated C value.

Note, Econ is a 2-dimensional, 1-based array. To select the first element: Econ(1, 1).

Difficult to really follow what you want to do, but maybe something like this:
Sub Macro_data_check()
   
   Dim c As Range, ws As Worksheet, v
   
   Set ws = ActiveSheet
   For Each c In ws.Range("C4:C350").Cells
        ws.Range("I1").Formula = c.Formula         'copy over formula
        v = ws.Range("S1").Value                   'check S1 value
        If v <> 0 Then
            c.Offset(0, 2).Value = v    'copy if non-zero
        Else
            'what if v=0 ?
        End If
   Next c

